# Cannot connect using new SSH key (rsa 4096)

Tags: linux, ssh

For an unknow reason, my work insist on using RSA 4096 ssh keys (even if they don't have passphrases) and therefore wants me to create a new pair (old current one is 'only' RSA 2048 with strong passphrase)

So I've moved my old pair to `.ssh/id_rsa_legacy` and `.ssh/id_rsa_legacy.pub`, then I created a new one with

```
ssh_keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -o -a 100
```

Sounds good so far, but wait !!!

If I do

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa_legacy.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && ssh localhost
```

I can connect, but if I do

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && ssh localhost
```

I get an error

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

Also, `ssh-add -l` shows both keys (old one first, then new one)

I've looked on stackoverflow & duckduckgo but all answers discussed adding the new key to using `ssh-add` which doesn't solves my case.

Comment: 1) Remove all keys from your `ssh-agent`: `ssh-add -D` and retry. 2) Try without `ssh-agent`: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK="" ssh localhost`